# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \sqrt{x^2 + 3x} - \sqrt{x^2 + x}$. Is Wolfram wrong or is it me?

Tags: calculus

What am I doing wrong?

**My attempt**
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to -\infty} \sqrt{x^2 + 3x} - \sqrt{x^2 + x} &= \lim_{x \to -\infty} \sqrt{x^2 + 3x} - \sqrt{x^2 + x} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 3x} + \sqrt{x^2 + x}}{\sqrt{x^2 + 3x} + \sqrt{x^2 + x}} =\\
&= \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 3x} + \sqrt{x^2 + x}} =\\
&= \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\frac1x \cdot 2x}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2} + \frac{3x}{x^2}} + \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2} + \frac{x}{x^2}}} = \\
&= \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + \frac3x} + \sqrt{1 + \frac1x}} = 1
\end{align}$$

**Wolfram result**

[image]

Comment: Possibly you make an error when calculating a square root. Most common mistake is taking $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ even if $x$ is *negative*.

Comment: Argh! Never write anything like that first line!

Comment: @Henning Why not? It would be a useful way of determining what kind of indeterminate form you're dealing with, as well as making sure that it can't be decided by pure substitution (as long as you make sure to stop at $\infty-\infty$). People write things like $\frac\infty\infty$ and $1^\infty$ all the time.

Comment: @Arthur: I'm objecting to the equals signs, not to shorthand classification of indeterminate limits in general.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Fair enough. I agree that $=$ is the wrong symbol.

Comment: Next time, instead of multiplying the denominator, simply factor out the greatest power from the square root and then check the sign of $x$. By writing $\sqrt{x^2 + x} = |x|\sqrt{1 + \frac1x}$ there is virtually zero chance to make a mistake.

Comment: Henning Makholm's comment above refers to the original post, where the first line was an equation involving infinity.  The edit by rubik removed this line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your way to the last line, you're tacitly assuming that, for example, $\frac1x\sqrt{x^2+x} = \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{x}{x^2}}$. But that is only true when $x$ is positive!

When $x$ is negative, $\frac1x\sqrt{\cdots\vphantom{x}}$ will be negative, and thus it can never be written as a sum of square roots.

Comment: Thank you very much. sorry, I dont know how to write here math things so, always when I'm gonna put some "x" inside de sqrt, if x is negative, I need to assume that (1/x)*sqrt(x^2) = - sqrt (1) = -1 no? thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Your error is when you divided the numerator by $x$ but you divided the denominator by $\sqrt{x^2}$.  Note that when $x$ is negative, $\sqrt{x^2}$ is positive.

Comment: So, since $x<0$, when you divided the denominator by $\sqrt{x^2}$, you should have divided the numerator by $-x$.

Answer (score 1):

Well very obviously Wolfram's answer is incoherent, since the constant term in the expansion at infinity and the limit should be equal. Your reasoning, however, fails on the last line, since $x\sqrt{a}$ does not equal $\sqrt{x^{2}a}$ as $x$ goes to minus infinity, but $-\sqrt{x^{2}a}$ instead.